# Banner de AdMob no aparece en dispositivo, pero sí en emulador

Tags: java, android, admob

He creado una app para android y al llegar el momento de poner anuncios con AdMob, he seguido las instrucciones de la página oficial, añadiendo todas las líneas de código necesarias para ello.

Mi problema resulta en que a la hora de poner en el emulador un banner de test, sí aparece perfectamente. Publiqué mi app en Google Play pensando que aparecerían los anuncios en la app, pero no es así, lo he probado con otro dispositivo ajeno a mi cuenta.

Aquí dejo los fragmentos de código, para ver si alguien puede ayudarme y encontrar cuál es el problema:

**activity_titulo.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="id_de_bloque" />
```

**Titulo.java**

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "id_de_app");

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**manifest**

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".Titulo">
                    android:label="@string/app_name">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Frases" />

        <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
```

Como ya he dicho, mi problema radica en que los anuncios no aparecen en los dispositivos, pero sí el banner "test" en el emulador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de solucionar su problema es utilizando el metodo addTestDevice() de la clase AdRequest y pasarle como parametro AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "id_de_app");

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Precisamente eso es lo que me funciona. Mi problema es que los anuncios no se muestran en el dispositivo, aun con la app publicada en Google Play.

Comment: **Usar AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR es únicamente para desarrollo** no para una aplicación destinada a Google Playstore